# Configuring Log Shipping For Multiple Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, log-shipping

Can any body explain quick way to configure logshipping for 50 databases on multiple servers?.
I know how to configure log shipping but i want the quickest way to configure log shipping say for 50 databases on multiple server?
Can any one provide me the step by step to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered building the first one, scripting the jobs and parameterizing the jobs?

This may not be the best solution, but it should generally work.  The good news is if you want o change them all, you may have ease of doing this...however, if you want them all different, there may not be a quick solution.